# Multiple repositories (Maven / Pip) and protobuffers - best project setup?

Tags: java, python, maven, pip, protocol-buffers

we would like to go Open Source with our (almost completed) project, an agent-based simulation framework.
The main part of this framework is written in Java, data input is done via Google protobuffer files which are generated and organized by a configuration tool written in Python.
We are looking for the best way to make our project easily accessible
-           via Maven for the Java part (not local)
-           via Pip/Conda for the Python part

So far, we have three repositories separated by programming language: One for Java code, one for Python code, and one repo for the protobuffer definitions;
Our question is: How to deal with
·       the Java and Python classes compiled by the protobuffer compiler and
·       the corresponding maven scripts, which support the compilation (basically order a “recompile” once protobuffer definitions change)

Our ideas to solve this are:

A)      Since the compiled protobuffer classes are required for the code in the other repositories, we think we also need to add the compiled classes to the third repository, not just the protobuffer definitions.

a.       Benefit: protobuffer stuff encapsuled in one repo

b.       Drawback: Storing compilation results in repo / multiple languages in one repo

B)      We could store only protobuffer definitions in the third repo, move compilation scripts to the other two repositories and “source” the protobuffer definitions somehow across repositories.

a.       Benefit: clean separation of repos by coding language; no compiled code in repo

b.       Drawback: more dependencies & higher config complexity in Java and Python repos

We are quite unexperienced in publishing code open source and have the feeling that we haven’t got the simplest project setup to get started with doing so ^^.
Therefore, your help would be highly appreciated, since existing help on Stackoverflow and the web did not get us there.

Thank you very much for your suggestions!

Comment: Have you thought of having docker with dependencies.

Comment: Unfortunately, docker is a) no option for us (being at a research institute with strict software rules) and b) I am not quite sure how that would solve our problem with being easily accessible via Maven and Pip...

Comment: I have seen situations where docker images being used to host dependencies locally.